# How to prevent form's action to occur in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a form with action="xyz.aspx:type=new" and some input textboxes and 2 buttons: Submit and Preview. The Submit button updates the database with textbox values and Preview button carries the form textbox values to page "xyz.aspx?type=preview" . The problem is that the functiobalities are achieved but after clicking Preview button, the form's action url gets into action and causes an update in the database which is not wanted. So how do I prevent this from happening? ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some example code of what happens at your page_load?

Answer (score 1):

If your two buttons are not asp:Buttons, do that first.

```
<asp:Button Id="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_OnClick"/>
<asp:Button Id="Preview" runat="server" OnClick="Preview_OnClick"/>
```

Now, move your code to update the database into `Submit_OnClick`

```
protected void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //update your database
}
```

Your database should only be updated when Submit is clicked.

If you need your Preview  button to post to another page, use the PostBackUrl property.

Comment: Thanks! But I have a common page to display on clicking Submit and Preview buttons. The only diffidence is that after Submit it will populate values from dbase and Preview from querystring. But why does the form action gets fired after Preview. The Preview click  code contains just the redirect url.

Comment: If you have code in your Page Load event, it will fire for any control that causes a post back. We would need to see your code to know any more.